# In a Spring boot test, how can I create a bean and injects by @Autowired?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing

When I test my Spring boot service I don't know how I can inject an @Autowired bean.

My bean (Spring fills @Value from application.yml):

```
@Component
public class NavigatorProperties {
    @Value("${timerDelay}")
    private String timerDelay;

    public String getTimerDelay() {
        return timerDelay;
    }
    public void setTimerDelay(String timerDelay) {
        this.timerDelay = timerDelay;
    }
}
```

My api:

```
public class ListenerApi implements IRestListenerApi {
    @Autowired
    private NavigatorProperties np;

    public String doSomething (...) { // This is my service method.
        // Here np.getTimerDelay() will return application.yml value.
        int timerDelay = Integer.decode(np.getTimerDelay());
        ...
    }
}
```

This works fine and int value is correct. Here is my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ListenerApiTest.class, NavigatorProperties.class})
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class ListenerApiTest {
    @Autowired
    private NavigatorProperties np; // Can be autowired or a new Object.

    // Object to test.
    private ListenerApi listenerApi;

    @Test
    public void test01ForceNumberFormatException() {
        np.setTimerDelay("NumberFormatException");
        // Inyect into ListenerApi
    }

    @Test
    public void test02ForceNullPointerException() {
        np.setTimerDelay(null);
        // Inyect into ListenerApi
    }
```

In this test comments, how I can inyect into ListenerApi by @Autowired?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you what ListenerApiTest class file, I think bean is initialized there itself and you possibly are mixing config bean definition and annotations.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Can;t you just put `@Autowired` on ListenerApi

Comment: You can use `@ContextConfiguration` and point to the right `@Configuration` class for your stuff, then use `@Autowired` on the `ListenerApi` instance.  But if this is a unit test rather than integration test, it probably makes as much sense to use constructor injection and just _construct_ the needed items in your test...

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to annotate your dependency with `org.springframework.stereotype.Component`.

```
@Component
public class ListenerApi implements IRestListenerApi {
```

Then Inject it in wherever required :

```
@Autowired
private ListenerApi listenerApi;
```

Comment: Oh yes! This solution works with @Autowired ListenerApi... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your @SpringBootTest should be like:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ListenerApi.class, NavigatorProperties.class})
```

include every bean class that you want to inject into ListenerApiTest

Comment: Could you please add some informations, why this solves the questsion?

Answer (score 0):

Add component scan annotation with the package to scan

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.package.to.scan")
```